# Email group when documents reaches expiry date

Tags: workflow, feature

I have a requirement where a document column `‘Expiry’ = today` to send an email to the document owner / group. Then the owner will need to modify the document and update the Expiry Date ready for the next round.

The retention policy doesn’t work because retention occurs only once so another solution is required and was thinking of using a timer job to iterate the Document Library daily however if the library grows can this cause too much load on the server?

I have a number of websites that require this feature, each website has a different name but the same Document Library name. I want to create a single feature and apply on different sites. How can I do this as previously I needed to specify the path in the feature?

This is my retention settings, just in case this option can work:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way would probably be to create a timerjob which:

1. Iterate through your webs and find Doc Libraries with specific name.
2. Iterate through the documents to find an column with expired date, use lambda.
3. Mail targeted groups/users for the specified document.

As long as the timerjob doesnt run all the time you can minimize the workload.

Comment: Hi
Should this feature be Application/site/web feature? Can i add one feature and associate to many sites with same library name?
What is lambda?

Comment: When you say site do you mean sitecollections? In that case you can create a timerjob with Webapplication-scope. You will then only need one feature.
If you have a number of sites in a sitecollection then you can make the timerjob with site-scope.
Lambda is a good way to write query-code instead of standard Linq-query. 
Its fast and clean.
http://daniel.wertheim.se/2011/02/07/c-clean-up-your-linq-queries-and-lambda-expressions/

Comment: Hi
I have a site collection http://sharepoint/path/sitecollection and within this we have subsites which contain 3 libraries and folders. I want the contents of the folders in the 3 libraries iterated in all webs in site collection. I found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386186/how-to-loop-through-from-a-root-web-and-all-its-subsites
However I dont think this iterates the webs. Could you advise pls?

Comment: The link above has changed. Should be: http://danielwertheim.se/c-clean-up-your-linq-queries-and-lambda-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

**Recurring retention policies:**

You can create recurring steps in a retention policy:

> Additionally, it’s possible to create recurring steps in a retention policy. Your retention policy might simply send an e-mail to the owner of the document every year for them to review. If they decide the document is outdated, it can be left up to them to recycle the document manually. In that case, the recurring retention policy simply brings the document to someone’s attention to review for relevance.

Simply use the recurrence feature of a retention policy. For more complicated versions you can instantiate a workflow.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2011/10/03/applying-document-retention-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: I'm aware its possible to create reoccuring steps, but this is defined in the retention policy. The user wants the ability to set a DIFFERENT reminder date on each and every document. This is why I dont think the retention policy will work for me.

Comment: You can set the column to use in the Document Settings under "Information Management Policy Settings" "Time based on a property of the item"

Comment: My Mistake here, Though its possible to get a 'Time Period' column, once this expires the user is notefied by email workflow.Then the user changes the 'Review Date' for next time, however as the Retention has already fired it wont fire again and I cannot find a way of resetting this.Apparently this is normal behaviour. See added image in post pls. Thanks

Comment: The retention should restart when the updates are made, or just repeat on the current cycle.

Comment: 'The retention should restart when updates are made' - So if a user edits a document and updates the Review Date, should the retention stage restart taking into account the new Review Date even after it has previously executed?

Comment: You can set it up to do this, might require a workflow to be executed as a step for your exact purpose. But that's why you can use workflows because they can tweak the experience.

Comment: When the occurrence is enabled, the occurrence happens at defined points and doesn’t take the user input 'review date' into consideration. It only takes review date into consideration on the 1st occurrence, thereafter it relies on the predefined period. Hence it doesn’t work the way i need. Are you suggesting add a workflow to override this?

Comment: Override and act as the retention policy itself, pausing for the requried length of time

Answer (score 0):

Is it feasible for your owners to create alerts on the library/libraries?  If so then you could create a view filtered to show documents expiry date < [Today] and where owner = [Me].  You can then have alerts related to this specific view.

Comment: I will try that out. Whilst creating the doc library there was confusion over owner. There is 'Created By' but this is not always the owner. Word has an internal Owner tag, can this be surfaced to list level and used for document management purposes?